# Tags are cut off in the Android app on a Samsung Galaxy tablet

Tags: bug, android-app

The tags are cut off in the Android app on a Samsung Galaxy tablet

[image: screen shot]

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: samsung

Comment: I see this too, on a Galaxy Tab S2, 9.7".